# XAML databinding with String format with font

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Assuming Im binding a `TextBlock` Text property to a string in my viewModel.
My property represents a size, e.g `2.5M Items`, and I want to view it in my UI with two different fonts, so that my number (`2.5`) is big font and my suffix (`M`)  is smaller font.
Is there a way to do it with only one textblock binded property, Or I must separate it in my viewModel to `value` & `units` properties (feels a bit lame to do so imo)

Comment: you may perhaps use a converter to do this for you.

Comment: "Or I must separate it in my viewModel to value & units properties". Yes, I think that is what you should do. After all, the point in using MVVM is to be able to unit test your ViewModel. If you hide the value/units separation logic in your view, you cannot write unit tests for it.

Comment: It will be easier for you to seperate `value` and `units` instead of using only one textblock.

Answer (score -1):

If you unit property always display as "m", then You can use stringFormat to format string with Binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding value, StringFormat={}{0}m}" />
```